# Using Pillow to draw cursive text

Tags: ubuntu, fonts, python-imaging-library, ligature

I'm to draw text over an image in a Django application hosted on an `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS` machine. `Pillow 4.2.1` is my lib of choice.

I've successfully accomplished this task via `ImageDraw` imported from `PIL` (The actual code is at the end of this question)

My code works perfectly for languages such as English, French or Spanish.

But not for *naturally cursive* languages like Arabic, Persian or Urdu. In such cases, it draws each letter separately. E.g. `فارسی`(Persian) is drawn as:

[image]

Note that I installed `sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer` and tried `/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial.ttf` for this.

Someone [advised me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45554679/4936905) to make sure the font I'm using has **ligatures**. My understanding is that `Arial` does support ligatures, yet the problem persists.

**My question is:** what should I do to fix this issue? My code must support naturally cursive languages like Arabic, Persian or Urdu.

---

The code:

```
from PIL import ImageDraw
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
base_width, base_height = img.size
y = 2
for line in lines:
    width, height = font.getsize(line)
    x = (base_width - width) / 2
    text_with_stroke(draw,x,y,line,font,fillcolor,shadowcolor)
    y += height
```

where `text_with_stroke` is simply:

```
def text_with_stroke(draw,width,height,line,font,fillcolor,shadowcolor):
    draw.text((width-1, height), line, font=font, fill=shadowcolor)
    draw.text((width+1, height), line, font=font, fill=shadowcolor)
    draw.text((width, height-1), line, font=font, fill=shadowcolor)
    draw.text((width, height+1), line, font=font, fill=shadowcolor)
    draw.text((width, height), line, font=font, fill=fillcolor)
```

In a nutshell, this code breaks any given text into separate lines, taking into account the font size and underlying image size. It then iteratively draws each line of text on the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer for this problem is already tackled on this rather excellent SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25727238/4936905.

Essentially, two Python libraries are needed here: `BiDi` and `Arabic Reshaper`.

That's `pip install python-bidi` and `pip install git+https://github.com/mpcabd/python-arabic-reshaper`. The exact implementation entails transforming `text` as follows before drawing it via `PIL`:

```
reshaped_text = arabic_reshaper.reshape(line)
final_text = get_display(reshaped_text)

draw.text((width-1, height), final_text, font=font, fill=shadowcolor)
draw.text((width+1, height), final_text, font=font, fill=shadowcolor)
draw.text((width, height-1), final_text, font=font, fill=shadowcolor)
draw.text((width, height+1), final_text, font=font, fill=shadowcolor)
draw.text((width, height), final_text, font=font, fill=fillcolor)
```